# converting emoticon unicode which comes from mobile application for web application

Tags: php, code-composer

I was using emojione to convert emoticons but there is problem.

When someone upload emoticon from mobile then something like, \ud83d\ude0c\ud83d\ude0c\ud83d\ude0c this unicode.

emojione doesn't convert this type of code.

Can anybody help me to convert this code or suggest me to use any other package

Answer (score 0):

I have done @ last.

```
    $str   = '\ud83d\ude0c\ud83d\ude0c\ud83d\ude0c';
    $regex = '/\\\u([dD][89abAB][\da-fA-F]{2})\\\u([dD][c-fC-F][\da-fA-F]{2})
          |\\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/sx';
    echo preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {

        if (isset($matches[3])) {
            $cp = hexdec($matches[3]);
        } else {
            $lead  = hexdec($matches[1]);
            $trail = hexdec($matches[2]);

            // http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-4
            $cp = ($lead << 10) + $trail + 0x10000 - (0xD800 << 10) - 0xDC00;
        }

        // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-3
        // Characters between U+D800 and U+DFFF are not allowed in UTF-8
        if ($cp > 0xD7FF && 0xE000 > $cp) {
            $cp = 0xFFFD;
        }

        // https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.6.4/ext/standard/html.c#L471
        // php_utf32_utf8(unsigned char *buf, unsigned k)

        if ($cp < 0x80) {
            return chr($cp);
        } else if ($cp < 0xA0) {
            return chr(0xC0 | $cp >> 6) . chr(0x80 | $cp & 0x3F);
        }

        return html_entity_decode('&#' . $cp . ';');
    }, $str);
```

output will be: